# OuterTemplate.GetGroupName not working after October 2012 cumulative update

Tags: content-query-web-part, cumulative-update

We have customized content query web part by using custom header style xslt and item style xslt which are configured using properties 'HeaderXslLink' and 'ItemXslLink' respectively.

Also we are grouping data by categories using 'GroupBy' property.

---

Output of cqwp is as below.

## Group header 1

### Heading 1

Content

### Heading 2

Content

## Group header 2

### Heading 1

Content

and so one.

---

Prior to installing OCT CU 2012 this functionality was working as expected. However after installing  CU now Group Header is not shown. We have upgraded server from JUNE 2012 CU to OCT 2012 CU.

---

This is consistent behaviour on all the servers where OCT CU 2012 is installed.